# Display submitted XML data into a textfield

Tags: php, ajax, xml

i have been trying for the last few days days to figure this out to no avail, i am making a currency conversion form where you can post, delete and edit currencies so far i have that working. upon submit i have a function to send the data to the right php form and i stop the refresh using a hidden iframe(i know this is bad but i couldn't get the ajax to work with the function), what i am trying to do is once the user has clicked submit i want the xml they have just entered to be displayed in a response text field below with method they used and what time is was at.

sorry for the long question im new to ajax heres the code for the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnSubmitForm()

{

  if(document.myform.operation[0].checked == true)
{
   document.myform.action ="currPost.php";
}
 else
 if(document.myform.operation[1].checked == true)
{
  document.myform.action ="currPut.php";
}
else if(document.myform.operation[2].checked == true)
{
    document.myform.action ="currDel.php";
 }
return true;

}
</script>
```

heres what some of the submitted xml looks like

```
<currency>
<code rate="33">testagain2</code>
<cname>ew</cname>
<cntry>3232</cntry>
</currency>
</currencies>
```

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXZ5P.jpg "form"
any advice is appreciated

heres the form code with the removed jframe

```
 <!--tickboxes-->

 <form name="myform"    method="POST" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();">

   <input type="radio" name="operation" value="1" id="Post"      onclick="displayFunctionPost()"> Post
      <input type="radio" name="operation" value="2" id="Put" onclick="displayFunctionPut()"> Put
  <input type="radio" name="operation" value="3" id="Delete" onclick="displayFunctionDelete()"> Delete
 <br>
 Currency Code:
     <br>
    <input type="text" id="currency-code" placeholder="Code" disabled>
     <!--currency form-->
    <br>
     Currency Name
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="currency-name" placeholder="name" disabled>
    <br>
     <!---rates form--->    
     Rate (£=1):
     <br>
     <input type="number" id="rate" placeholder="rate" disabled>
 <!---countries form-->
     <br>
     Countries (comma separated if 1+)
     <br>
     <input type="text" id="countries" placeholder="countries" disabled>
    <br>
 <!---xml response--->
   <br>
    Response Message:
    <br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled id="response-xml" placeholder="Response XML">
     <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: add form code, did page reload after click submit?

Comment: added in the form code, without the jframe the form redirects to the pfp file, with the jframe the form doesn't reload